# Push Object to Array in Vue JS / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs3

I have this response from HTTP call:

[image]

It's an Array. Now, In my vue JS application I have a `projectFieldOptions` empty array property.

> projectFieldOptions: [],

Now, I want to make a object like that:

{
value : item // that response each array item name
text : item / /that response reach array item name
}

and want push it to `projectFieldOptions` emtpy array. So to do this I am using this code:

```
http.post("projects/import/", this.importData)
.then((response) => {
    let res = response.data;
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status == "pending") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.callHttp();
            this.loadDone = true;
        }, 5000);
    } else {
        this.loadDone = false;
        res.forEach(function(item){
            _this.projectFieldOptions.push({ value : item, text : item  });
        });
        console.log(this.projectFieldOptions);
    }
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
this.countHTTP++;
```

Here, You can see that I push to that empty array using this code:

> _this.projectFieldOptions.push({ value : item, text : item  });

But when I **console.log** this `projectFieldOptions` array I can see that array **item** is not parsing and showing me **item** as text not the actual **item** value. I mean it's showing this:

[image]

My questions is:

1. Why it's not adding the actual array item value to that empty array ?
2. why it's showing **Ob** (Observer) ?

Comment: the first result in the response has a value of `"item"` ... which is exactly what is in that array ... `{text: "item", value: "item"}` is exactly what you pushed ... what did you expect? the observer stuff is vuejs reactivity stuff you need not worry about

Comment: check what is in the second item of the array .. `{text: "title", value:"title"}`? the 3rd ... `{text: "short_message", value: "short_message"}` ... then `{text: "url", value: "url"}` ... can you see how that is exactly what you get from the response .. just those strings `["item", "title", "short_message", "url", ...]` ... what "object" were you actually expecting in there?

Comment: FYI you should use an arrow function in `setTimeout()`. Also, you can more simply just use `this.projectFieldOptions = res.map((item) => ({ value: item, text: item }));`